# Can an oxidising/reducing agent oxidise/reduce itself?

Tags: physical-chemistry, redox

I am new to the study of this divine science. So Just a query: Can an oxidising/reducing agent oxidise/reduce itself? **If it can can anyone give an example and explain it?**

Comment: You were told already in your prior question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A simple example can be the disproportionation of chlorine when bubbling a current of chlorine gas $\ce{Cl2}$  into a solution of $\ce{NaOH}$ (containing $\ce{OH^-}$ ions):
$$\ce{Cl2 + 2 OH^- -> ClO^- + Cl^- + H2O}$$
Here the chlorine atoms have the oxidation number equal to zero in the reactants, and get the final oxidation number $-1$ in $\ce{Cl^-}$ and $+1$ in $\ce{ClO^-}$.  Here one of the $2$ original $\ce{Cl}$ atoms oxidises the other one from $0$ to $+1$. In this operation it is reduced fro $0$ to $-1$.

The final solution is the famous bleach, used for cleaning dirty surfaces.

Comment: My answer has been downvoted. Why ? It is a perfect answer to the question as written in the title.